# Not able to upload image when there is no input id

Tags: testrigor

I have been trying to upload a file using testRigor. As there is no input id available I'm not able to upload the file.

I have tried uploading file using Xpath that I got from selectersshub.

- Login
- check that page contains "Dashboard"
- click on "My Info"
- click on "profile picture" below second "testGaurav testGaurav"
- check that page contains "Change Profile Picture"
- enter  "C:\Users\Rohit Khandagale\Desktop\Sample Test Files\png_file.png" into "profile picture"

can someone help me with this?
I'm trying this on the site below
https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login

Answer (score 0):

URL to the file needs to be publicly available. You can upload the file to Test Data, save it as file variable then enter into the input using:

**enter stored value "fileVariableName" into input file**